# fitnesse slim fixture variable substitution failure

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Currently I have a FitNesse Slim fixture written with a quick and easy method for processing:

```
public List<List<String>> doTable(List<List<String>> rows)
```

Everything is working just fine except for one problem:  page variables/expressions.

On the parent page I have a date/time variable defined:

```
!define myvar {!today (mmddhms)}
```

On the child page I have my table defined for processing following a similar pattern to the [RESTFixture](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixture) that is available on GitHub:

```
!| Table:my.domain.MyFixture |
| let | myinnervar | const | ${myvar} |
| uri | http://someuri.com:12345 |
| etc | etc.etc.etc. |
```

**The problem is:**

The `${myvar}` specification does not evaluate properly.  Instead of evaluating to a value such as `071511718` it shows up as the actual expression:  `!today (mmddhms)`.  I need it to evaluate as the proper expression.

In the RESTFixture table that is set up identically and anywhere else it evaluate just fine.  However, I am not seeing where the specialized processing code is defined  that allows it to properly evaluate.

Can anyone point to the appropriate code in that Fixture or just point me to some documentation.  I'm not seeing anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a literal table which means wiki markup is not interpreted inside the table.  Use a plain table and escape the cells that you don't want interpreted as wiki markup

```
| Table:my.domain.MyFixture |
| let | myinnervar | const | ${myvar} |
| uri | !-http://someuri.com:12345-! |
| etc | etc.etc.etc. |
```